# V-Calendar from vuetify don´t load my Events

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, momentjs

i want to create a Vuetify-Calendar in my Vue.js-Application.

This is how my calendar looks:

```
      <v-calendar
        class="mt-5 mb-5 rounded-xl"
        v-model="focus"
        ref="calendar"
        :weekdays="weekday"
        locale="de"
        :events="transformEvents"
        :show-month-on-first="false"
        color="primary"
        :type="type"
        :timezone="'Europe/Berlin'"
      >
      </v-calendar>
```

But the Timeline begins at 0 am.
How i can change it. That the timeline is only from 8 am to 17pm

Comment: Vue.js and Vuetify questions are highly version specific.  Please add additional tags or include the version information somewhere in your question.  It's also not clear what some of these values are since they're dynamic bindings.  `type`, `weekday`, `transformEvents`, etc.  Please review [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide more information so we understand exactly how the calendar is functioning.